# tail -f -n 1 returns all content of the file

Tags: command, tail

I have a `text.txt` file in Ubuntu.

I want to watch the file with `tail` for grabbing the last content of the file.

```
tail -f text.txt
```

this command returns all of the content.

So I changed it to :

```
tail -f -n 1 text.txt
```

but the same result again.

I examine the line of file with:

```
wc -l text.txt
```

when content is appended to file, the line number counts changes.

So first of all what's wrong?

Comment: What version of `tail` is this? I get the expected result with `tail (GNU coreutils) 8.28`

Comment: How many lines does your file have? And how exactly does `tail -f -n1` show all the content? Does it simply show new lines as they are written? Does this happen with all files or just a specific one?

Comment: @Panki tail (GNU coreutils) 8.28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tail -f` prints the last 10 lines of the file. Once it reaches the end of the file, it waits and prints everything that gets appended later. That's the principle of ***f**ollowing* a file's growth.

If you want to always “print the last 10 lines of the file”, that's not well-defined, since it depends on when it checks. If there's a program that prints one line at a time, and each time `tail` prints it immediately, `tail` *is* printing the last 10 lines of the file at any time.

If you want to periodically show the last few lines of the file but skip lines if there's rapid growth, you need a different approach than following_. For example, call `tail` in a loop. Don't use `-f` since you don't actually want to follow the file.

```
while sleep 1; do tail text.txt; done
```

If you want to keep the last few lines visible on the screen but hide older lines, the [`watch`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=watch&apropos=0&sektion=1) utility is convenient.

```
watch tail text.txt
```

Comment: tnx for answering my question. my original question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62791015/tail-f-n-1-returns-all-content-not-changes/   . as I mentioned there I need to watch my file when some action happens. I want to use child_process utility in nodejs for spawning tail command . as you said I have to use tail in a loop . is it efficent?running a child_proccess over and over again and killing it?

Comment: @babakabadkheir If you need to watch content that gets appended to the file, you presumably need the whole content. But why would you use the shell command instead of the nodejs tail package?